# c++ heap or stack allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

This is an allocation on the stack:

```
char inStack[10]; 
// and 
MyStruct cl;
```

And this should be allocated in the heap:

```
char* inHeap = new char[10];
// and
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
```

What if `MyClass` contains a `char test[10]` variable? Does this:

```
MyClass cl = new MyClass()
```

...mean that the 10 byte long content of `MyClass::test` is allocated in the heap instead of the stack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be allocated inside the object, so that if the object is on the heap, the array will be on the heap; if the object is on the stack, the array will be on the stack; if the object is in static memory in the executable, the array will be there also.

In C++, members of objects are part of the object itself. If you have the address of the object and it's size, you know that all the members of the class will be somewhere within the range `[address, address + size)`, no matter where in memory that address actually is (heap, stack, etc).

Comment: Perhaps,I guess i will delete the statement for not causing any confusions.

Answer (score 5):

If `MyClass` has a `char test[10]` member, it will be allocated the **same way** the instance of `MyClass` was allocated.

```
MyClass mc; //mc.test is on the stack
MyClass * mcp = new MyClass; //mcp->test is on the heap
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper terms in the language are *automatic* and *dynamic* storage, and these make a bit more sense than *stack* and *heap*. In particular *automatic* storage does not imply stack in general, only in local variables in functions, but as you mention, if you are defining a member of a class, automatic storage will be wherever the enclosing object is, which can be the stack, the heap or a static object.